# How to push all zip files on my specific folder to my s3 bucket folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have problem where I can't push through all of my zip files to my s3 bucket, it happens right now when i run the bat files it just a second of loading of cmd and it will automatically close. when i refresh my s3 bucket folder there is no copy of zip files.

Command:

[image: Command]

AWS S3 BUCKET:

[image: my bucket]

My Script:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/07-08-2020/*.zip  C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder --recursive
```

Comment: The command copies from S3 -> local folder. You want to copy from local -> S3?

Comment: yes. from my desktop folder to s3 bucket

Comment: what i mean. i want to push all my zip files on my local computer to my aws s3 bucket

Comment: Can you try the other way around: `aws s3 cp  C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder\*.zip  s3://my_bucket/07-08-2020/ --recursive`. I'm not sure of windows syntax, but local folder should be first, s3 folder (destination) second. 
`

Comment: let me try of this script

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: @Marcin it says that the user-provided path C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder\*.zip does not exist

Comment: Can you go into the folder `C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder` and run the command from there: `aws s3 cp  *.zip  s3://my_bucket/07-08-2020/`?

Comment: i will replace my command first?

Comment: i try your script command and it says that : The user-provided path *.zip does not exist?

Comment: do you have zip files in `C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder`?

Comment: yes i have. here is the sample name. 0109exp.zip , 0321exp.zip

Comment: Can you copy individual files: `aws s3 cp  C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder\0109exp.zip  s3://my_bucket/07-08-2020/`?

Comment: yah it works if individual files

Comment: `aws s3 cp C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder  s3://mybucket/ --recursive --include "*.zip"` seems like wildcard issue in window. can try this command from the root foold and include only zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AmitBaranes is right. I checked on a Windows box. You could also simplify your command by using [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) instead of `cp`.

So the command using `sync` could be:

```
aws s3 sync "C:\first_folder\second_folder\update_folder" s3://my_bucket/07-08-2020/ --exclude "*" --include "*.zip"
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the `*.zip`. In order to copy file with specific extension use the following syntax :

```sh
aws s3 cp [LOCAL_PATH] [S3_PATH] --recursive  --exclude "*" --include "*.zip"
```

From the docs:

> Note that, by default, all files are included. This means that
> providing only an --include filter will not change what files are
> transferred. --include will only re-include files that have been
> excluded from an --exclude filter. **If you only want to upload files
> with a particular extension, you need to first exclude all files, then
> re-include the files with the particular extension**.

More info can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters).